# Is is possible to re-arrange this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm writing some software and need to find the value of $w$ in this equation.

The equation is:  $w+pw+n(w-z)=x$

$p$ and $n$ are both values less than $1$ (in fact they are a percentage)

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since

$$w+pw+n(w-z)=w+pw+nw-nz=w(1+p+n)-nz\;,$$

you simply rearrange the equation first to

$$w(1+p+n)=x+nz$$

and then to

$$w=\frac{x+nz}{1+p+n}\;.$$

Comment: ... with the condition that $1+p+n\neq 0$, although being percentages this will never happen...

Comment: @pbs: It follows from the OP’s description that $p,n\ge 0$.

Comment: Thank you. Your first break down was what I couldn't see. It's been a long time since I did this sort or Maths

Comment: @Fran: You’re welcome.